# Is the quasi-projective scheme morphism separated and finite type?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-schemes

Is the quasi-projective scheme morphism separated and finite type?
In Hartshorne's book, it is shown when it is noetherian, but I was wondering if this assumption is necessary.

Comment: See here: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01VV

Comment: Thank you. The definition of algebraic varieties is a finite type, separated and integral scheme. I wanted to ask this question because the classical definition of algebraic varieties can be regarded as a quasi-pojective scheme.

Comment: That definition of varieties only holds for varieties over an algebraically closed field $k$ (if you want to talk about varieties over non-algebraically closed fields you usually take reduced separated schemes of finite type). That being said, even over algebraically closed fields $k$, it is possible to have non-quasi-projective varieties (for instance see Hartshorne Appendix B for an example due to Hironaka or here http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/0506-216/216class4344.pdf)

Comment: @Geoff it looks like your comments form an answer - would you care to record them as such below?